# Настройка VPN Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

При настройке VPN в Windows 10, что указывать в поле "имя или адрес сервера" - т.е какой ip ? Взависимости от региона в котором я хочу что бы считали что я нахожусь? Как не попасть тогда на чужую машину?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IP сервера, который предоставляет услуги VPN.
2. По идее, у тебя должны спросить логин и пароль при попытке подключения=> попасть на чужую машину нельзя